# Firefox or something else blocking requests randomly?

Tags: firefox, https

I am observing a pattern of requests being "Blocked" without apparent reason. See the screenshot. What seems like the same or similar requests get blocked and then they get through. Has anyone else observed this well?

[image]

Comment: Click on Tracking Protection icon to the left of url bar. Does it indicate content is being blocked for some reason?

Comment: @user3169 I have it set to Standard mode and it says "None Detected" on top of the list.